# flatMap function of List in Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, scala-collections, flatmap

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
val f = l flatMap (_ + 1)
```

I am running the above piece of code in Scala and I am getting the below error.

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
       val f = l flatMap (_ + 1)
```

What `flatMap` does is that it executes the map function that we provide (in this case ->: _ + 1) and then it iterates the resultant of map function. If iterator is not available on the map output, it throws this error.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would advice you to take a look to the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but the function you pass to `flatMap` should produce a `List` itself. What you're looking for is simply `map`:

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
val f = l map (_ + 1)
```

`flatMap` is (as the name suggests) consecutive `map` and `flatten`. The latter in case of `List`turns a nested collection into a flat one:

```
val nestedList: List[List[A]] = ???
val flattenedList: List[A] = nestedList.flatten
```

Your example would work if you passed a function producing `List` to `flatMap`, examples:

```
val res1 = l.flatMap(el => List(el + 1)) // add 1 to every element - same as with map above
val res2 = l.flatMap(el => List(el, 1)) // add 1 after every element
```