# Why does (x => x) prevent an error when destructuring a list of Option?

Tags: scala

I know that if I don't provide a fallback case, this flatMap will result in a MatchError when it tries to deconstruct `None`:

```
List(Some(3), None, Some(4)).flatMap { 
    case Some(n) => List(n) 
    case _ => Nil // this is required (otherwise you'll get a MatchError)
} // List(3, 4)
```

But then, why does this work?

```
List(Some(3), None, Some(4)).flatMap(x => x) // List(3, 4)
```

Comment: JFYI the second one is effectively `List(Some(3), None, Some(4)).flatten`.

Comment: Option is implicitly convertible to a collection of one element, so `.flatMap(x => x)` is effectively the same thing as you first snippet. Some other ways to write it are `flatMap(_.fold(Nil)(Seq.apply))`, `.flatMap(identity)` or just `.flatten` as suggested in the other comment. These are all equivalent.

Comment: `List.flatMap` works with any `IterableOnce` and `Option` is an `IterableOnce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flatMap` is effectively [`map` + `flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136718/2501279), the passed expression would be used for `map` part, so in the second case you are passing identity function for the `map` so it can be skipped completely, while in the first case you are passing a custom function which will perform pattern matching on the passed input of type `Option[Int]` which result in the mentioned *"Match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input: None"* error (for arguably obvious reasons).

The same behavior can be observed by switching `flatMap` to `map`.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first case you are using pattern matching to actively deconstruct the `Option` based on its cases `Some` and `None`: if it's `Some(n)`, take the `n` and put it in a `List`, if it's anything else (in this case this means `None`), produce the empty list.

In the second case, you are saying: whatever comes in, put it back there as it was. If it's `Some(n)` return `Some(n)`, if it's `None` return `None`. What happens at this point is that Scala has an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable` (after all, `Option` can be viewed as a `List` which can have at most one item).

This implicit conversion is basically equivalent to the pattern matching expression you highlighted above, getting to the same result.

You can see the implicit conversion definition [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1bdf362b0d8344927460116380b67fcaa766435b/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L19-L21).

This behavior is sometimes seen as a potential source of bugs, which is why WartRemover has [a built-in for it](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#option2iterable). Citing its documentation:

> Scala inserts an implicit conversion from Option to Iterable. This can hide bugs and creates surprising situations like Some(1) zip Some(2) returning an Iterable[(Int, Int)].